# how to show un-committed changes in a database table in datagrip

Tags: datagrip, intellij-datagrip

How can I run a statement in the sql query console in manual mode on datagrip and see their effect on the table locally in order to make sure it has the intended effect before committing it to the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a context action "Preview update".
(right click on statement > show context actions)

Answer (score 1):

From DataGrip 2020.2 you can review the query that represents your changes in the data editor.

**DML** button is active if there are pending changes:
[image: DML Preview]

Comment: I went to the table, right-clicked on it and jumped to a query console, set my mode to manual and then executed all the statements. but when I went back to the table view tab, my DML was still grayed out. My console view of that same table indicates there are pending changes and the green check mark for committing is active but when I go the table view, the DML button is still grayed out.

Comment: Could you file an issue in DataGrip bug tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/DBE and attach a screen cast with the problem?

Comment: can't seem to load that page. just got blank, these are the console message if relevant https://imgur.com/a/e5Lzl3Z

Comment: Kinda strange, let's try this one https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=DBE

Comment: let it load for 20 minutes and same deal. this is all I could see https://imgur.com/a/3XcgYJz . is that normal?

Comment: never mind, its working now. wonder what was going on there before

Comment: ah, the issue is that I was running a slightly older version of firefox on one of my machines.

Comment: So, what about the issue?

Comment: apparently what I had wanted was actually a context action. an intellij rep responded and said  `There is a context action "Preview update" (right click > show context actions)`

Answer (score 1):

See here the one highlighted in red "Preview Pending Changes", it will open the DML Preview modal.
[image]